# Free video editing software that supports panning with Bezier curves

Tags: video-editor, editing, software-recommendation

I'm trying to make a video by panning through cells in a webcomic. First I tried Kdenlive, but that seems to only support linear panning, so you can't do it smoothly. I found someone complaining about it that said Cinlerra can do it, but I downloaded and tried that out and the camera seems to stop at every waypoint. Is there software that lets me continuously and smoothly move the camera? Or if Cinlerra does it, can someone link me to something that says how?

Comment: If you want software that is free as in beer, try Lightworks - http://www.lwks.com/

Comment: Or Davinci resolve if you have the hardware to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Blackmagic Design Fusion 8 is up for the challange.
It is a very high-end compositing application.
Available on Mac and Windows, and as of now completely free.

You might need to find some tutorials to show you how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try HitFilm 3 Express. I believe that will do what you're looking for. [HitFilm 3 Express](https://hitfilm.com/express)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as if the link goes down then so does the answer. Please include at least some of the steps that the link includes here on the answer.

Comment: The question is about identifying a software that does what the OP wants. This answer provides that, accurately or otherwise. The OP hasn't asked for a tutorial on how to accomplish the task in the identified software. So, there are no "steps" to expound upon.

Answer (score 0):

[Natron](http://natron.fr/) does this. It is a pretty new open source node-based compositing software which is multi platform. The developers have been very quick to put something which is already impressive. If you know Nuke, you should get up and running pretty quickly.

Another compositing software which is free but not open source is [Blackmagic Fusion](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/fusion). They bought eyeon Software in 2014 and now provide this amazing software for free.